# Access to attribute and method in OOP

Tags: python, oop

i'm a beginner in python and starting  to learn OOP and the class way of programming

so i came across the following code :

```
class Employee :
    def __init__(self,name,age,salary):
        self.name ,self.age ,self.salary = name , age ,salary
    def __str__(self) -> str:
         return f'Employee name is {self.name} and {self.age} years old and is given a {self.salary} EGP a month  '


class EmployeeManger:
    Employee_list = []

    def add_Employee(self) :
        print('\n adding a new employee\n') 
        name = input ('Please enter employee name : \n ')
        age  = input ('Please enter employee age : \n ')
        salary  = input ('Please enter employee salary : \n ')
        EmployeeManger.Employee_list.append(Employee(name,age,salary))
        print(EmployeeManger.Employee_list[0])

    def list_Employee(self) :
        if len(EmployeeManger.Employee_list) == 0 :
            print('No Employee Entered Yet')
        else :
            for emp in EmployeeManger.Employee_list :
                print(emp)

    def delete_Employee_with_age (self,start_age,end_age) :

        for x in range(len(EmployeeManger.Employee_list)-1,-1,-1):
            y = EmployeeManger.Employee_list[x]
            if start_age <= int(y.age) <=end_age :
                print(f'\nDeleteing {y.name}') 
                EmployeeManger.Employee_list.pop(x)
    
    def find_by_name(self,S_name) :
        
        for y in EmployeeManger.Employee_list :
            if y.name == S_name :
                print(f'the name is found and {x.name} is a employee') 
            else :
                print('Not found ')
```

in line ( 31 and 38 ) i can't understand y.age and  y.name  what does it refer to ? and can someone please explain how python was able to access those values and understand those values as can't find where it was defined for it ?

i hope i made the question as clear as possible

Comment: `y.age` is trying to access the `.age` attribute of whatever `y` is. `y.name` is trying to access whatever the `.name` attribute of `y` is.

Comment: "please explain how python was able to access those values " Python attempts to access those attributes at runtime. Looking at this code, it looks like your `EmployeeManger.Employee_list` is populated by `Employee` objects in `add_Employee`, so at runtime, no errors will be raised.

Comment: There are quite a few anti-patterns in this code; I wouldn't recommend treating this as a good way of writing Python code.